# Custom post with author

Tags: php, wordpress

So for my custom post I need to put the user id into the "author" parameter as shown below:

```
$args = array(   
    'paged'=>$paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,         
    'orderby' => 'date',            
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'author' => ''
);
```

For example, I am in a "Ryan" profile page. The URL is as following:

```
http://example.com/?page_id=10&up_username=Ryan
```

If I am in "Steve" profile page, then the URL is as below:

```
http://example.com/?page_id=10&up_username=Steve
```

Each user has their own `ID`.

For example, "Ryan" has ID of 35 while Steve has "ID=12"

If I put the ID number in the `author` parameter, then I get the posts based on the ID number.

For example,

I put `'author' => '35'`, then I see Ryan's post.

Now, how can I make it so that the `"author"` parameter automatically picks up the ID number from the profile page?

I got some help (shown below) but it is not working.

```
// Default to false in case user can't be found.
$user_id  = false;
// Clean username variable before use.
$username = ( ! empty( $_GET['up_username'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field(  $_GET['up_username'] ) : false;
// Check for user ID.
if ( $username && $user = get_user_by( 'slug', $username ) ) {
    $user_id = $user->ID;
}   
$args = array(         
    'paged'=>$paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,         
    'orderby' => 'date',            
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'author' => $user_id    
);
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

**EDIT**

From digging around, I found some info:

```
function id_to_member( $user_id ) {
    $res = '';
    $nice_url = userpro_get_option('permalink_type');
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    if ($nice_url == 'ID') $res = $user_id;
    if ($nice_url == 'username') $res = $user->user_login;
    if ($nice_url == 'name') {
        $res = $this->get_fullname_by_userid( $user_id );
    }
    if ($nice_url == 'display_name'){
        $res = userpro_profile_data('display_name', $user_id);
    }
    if ($res != '')
        return $res;
   }
```

and

```
 <a href="#" data-up_username="<?php echo $userpro->id_to_member($user_id); ?>" data-template="view" class="userpro-button secondary"><?php _e('View Profile','userpro') ?></a>
```

**EDIT 2**

So, I realized that the profile page was generated by plugin (API: http://userproplugin.com/userpro/docs/api.html)

I used the following and was able to get the user data:

```
<?php
global  $userpro ; 
$user_id = userpro_get_view_user( get_query_var('up_username') );   
?>

<div class="user">
    <?php echo userpro_profile_data( display_name, $user_id ); ?>  
</div>
```

So, I am in "ryan's page" and I was able to output "Ryan", which means I am getting awfully close to "extract" the ID of the user.

Now, all I need to do is somehow find out the ID from this info.

Comment: and what are you getting ?

Comment: I am just getting the page author (admin) posts and not the profile user post.

Comment: Can you output this value for me? `$nice_url = userpro_get_option('permalink_type');`

Comment: I got "display_name" as the output (`<?php echo $nice_url = userpro_get_option('permalink_type');?>`)

Comment: You are already getting `$user_id` is this he current user id ? if it is, then you are done with it .. just pass this `$user_id` in the `get_user_by('id', $user_id)` and you will get the WP_User object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I read [here](https://github.com/bradryan13/userpro-custom/blob/1a1ddf6ebe6df8913bb2d83076e841b28d6785a3/functions/api.php):

```
global $userpro;

$args = array(         
    'paged'=>$paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,         
    'orderby' => 'date',            
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'author' => $userpro->get_member_by_queryvar_from_id()
);
```

Give that a shot.

Comment: IT WORKED!! :D FINALLY!:D Yay Thank you so much! can't believe how long it took to get it working! Could not have it done without your help!

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU ! :D

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

`author_name` instead of `author`.

```
$args = array(         
    'paged'=>$paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,         
    'orderby' => 'date',            
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'author_name' => empty($_GET['up_username'])?false:$_GET['up_username']
);
```

Comment: Hmm, having "author_name" shows no posts... (like it does not generate any). :(

Comment: What happens if you hardcode "Ryan" for author_name rather than using a parameter?

Comment: Hi. So, I tried few things : 1- `'author_name' = >'ryan'` (or "Ryan"): No posts (Not even admins'), 2- `'author_name' = >' '`: Shows admin's post. 3- `'author' => '35'`: Shows Ryan's post.   So looks like only the ID number is valid as the "author" parameter. Do you know if I can somehow extract the ID number of the profile user? (Based on the URL parameter).

Comment: I also found some info (See edit section). I am not sure if it will help.

Comment: I added a new answer based on the information you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

What if you tried using `'login'` rather than `'slug'` in your get_user_by(...) call in your initial code?

Comment: sigh,, no :( I am trying some other ways using this info (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by)...

Answer (score 1):

Display Names don't have to be unique, so this should search for all users with a given display name. Then join them with a comma before preforming your paginated search:

```
$usersMatchedWithDisplayName=array();
if(!empty($_GET['up_username']))
{
        $user_query = new WP_User_Query(array(
          'search' => $_GET['up_username'],
          'search_fields' => array('display_name')
        ));
    if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) )
    {
        foreach ( $user_query->results as $user )
        {
            $usersMatchedWithDisplayName[]=$user->ID;
        }
    }
}

$authors=implode(',',$usersMatchedWithDisplayName);

$args = array(         
    'paged'=>$paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,         
    'orderby' => 'date',            
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'author' => $authors
);
```

Comment: Hmm... just realized that should be `$user->ID` with caps. :Edits:

Comment: So, I included the `Edit 2` above. I am getting awfully close! :D

Answer (score 1):

According to [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters), WP_Query accept

- author (int) - use author id.
- author_name (string) - use 'user_nicename' - **NOT name**.

You can get user nice name by:

```
$user = get_user_by( 'id', 35 ); // Ryan ID is 35, TODO: you can get this from query string
```

And then pass this user id in `$args`:

```
$args = array(         
    'paged'=>$paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,         
    'orderby' => 'date',            
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'author_name' => $user->user_nicename
);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. Could you be able to show me how I can get the user id ("35" in this case) which is taken from profile user name based on the URL (http://example.com/?page_id=10&up_username=Ryan)? Thank you.

Comment: I added  "Edit 2" which I am getting really close to get this done.